# Stable and fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Can you help me understand the difference between a stable and a fixed point of an ODE $x' = f(x)$ ?

Let me tell you what I think. 
Let $x$ be a stable point. Then that means that $f(x)=x$.

Now let $x$ be a fixed point. Then $f(x)=o$.

This is what i've understood so far but I can't really tell the difference and I have the feeling that the definitions I gave above might be correct in a reverse order. If someone can clear it up for me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Term "fixed point" is often used for both differential equations $x' = f(x)$ and for maps $\overline{x} = F(x)$. Some people use term "equilibrium" or "steady point/state" to call the point $x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0) = 0$, and sometimes $x_0$ is called fixed point too. But for maps fixed point is always $F(x_0) = x_0$.

Comment: I'm studying dynamic systems and at the part of the book about stability it says that fixed point is $f(x_{0})=0$ . But now I am at discrete time dynamical systems and the teacher said that fixed point is, as you said, $F(x_{0})=x_{0}$ .But I suppose in both cases we have to do with differential equations.. Also English isn't my mother language so I'm not entirely sure how all these terms translate to English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s consider a continuous-time dynamical system $\dot{x} = f(x)$ and a discrete-time dynamical system $x_{t+1} = F(x_t)$.
Then:

- A state $x$ is a **fixed point**, if it does not evolve to another state under the given dynamics. This is equivalent to $f(x)=0$ and $F(x)=x$, respectively.
- A fixed point is **stable**, if it is attracting all states in its vicinity, i.e., those states converge towards the fixed point over time.
  This is equivalent to the Jacobian of $f$ having only eigenvalues with negative real parts or $\left| F'(x)\right| < 1$ (for sufficiently smooth $F$).
  A typical illustration of this are the states of a ball residing on some geography.
  If the ball is not moving, it is located at a fixed point.
  However:

  - If the ball rests in a valley, this is a stable fixed point: It will always roll back into the valley if slightly perturbed.
  - If the ball resides on the top of a hill, this fixed point is not stable: It will roll away from the fixed point when slightly perturbed.

Comment: I understand ! I wasn't aware that it's different for discrete and continuous system. Thank you very much

Comment: So a fixed point for a continuous system is the same as an equilibrium point ? and we get the same property as in dicrete systems if we consider the evolution function i.e $\phi_{t}(x)=x$ for all t

Comment: @JEJ: Yes and yes.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing discrete dynamics
$$
x_{n+1}=F(x_n)
$$
and continuous dynamics
$$
y'(t)=f(y(t))
$$
In both cases the dynamical behavior is stationary if the solution sequence resp. function are constants $x_n\equiv x^*$ resp. $y(t)\equiv y^*$.

For the discrete system this means that $x^*=F(x^*)$ which in other words describes a fixed point of $F$

In the continuous case the derivative of a constant is zero, so one has to look for points with $0=f(y^*)$, that is the roots of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !